# Is there any work around to load pdf stream in iframe or object in IE browser

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, pdf

I am sending base64 string from MVC controller and in ajax success I am rendering it as PDF using follow code.
  $("#imageParent").html(' ');

This code works for Chrome and Mozilla Firefox but not working on IE.After lot of search I found that IE doesn't  provide Content-Disposition through data attribute.

Is there any work around we have to solve this issue,As I dont have physical path of this file I need to load actual data into iframe or object.

Thanks in Advance..!!!

Comment: The package [PDF.js by Mozilla](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) can do this. It's the best cross-browser way to render PDFs in the browser, and can accept URLs or base64 data (and more). Might be the best step.

Comment: Can you please provide any example to how use it with iframe and base64 pdf string in jQuery. It would be really helpful to me if you give just small example of this

Comment: @samiles Thanks for your help..now PDF rendered in IE but it doesn't have any download or print type of functionality,which automatically came for other browsers..Any help or suggestion on this would be much appreciated.